# Android DeviceAdmin Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: android, exception, android-intent

Please if someone can help would be great.
I have looked at solutions provided elsewhere and they dont seem to resolve my problem.

I am using the the DeviceAdminReceiver and have testing lock device when button is pressed.
It actually does work but the first time I run the application I get an Activity crash.
(this crash will only happen once the first time it is run).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver c: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.deviceadmin.MainActivity$myAdmin; no empty constructor
```

I have tried lots of things to solve this problem:

1) Adding constructor to the subclass of DeviceAdminReceiver
2) Calling Super inside the constructor.

This are the solutions that I have seen suggested but it does not work.

Here is simplified code of my app:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
protected static final int REQUEST_ENABLE = 0;
private static final String LOG = "adminClient";
private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
private ComponentName mAdminName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, myAdmin.class);
    Log.d(LOG, "mAdminName = " + mAdminName.toString());

    Button deviceLock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    deviceLock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(LOG, "LockPhone clicked");
            lockPhone();
        }

    });

}





protected void lockPhone() {
       if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
            mAdminName);
            intent.putExtra("force-locked", DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK);        
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);
            } 
           else {   
            Log.d(LOG, "lockDown phone");
            mDPM.lockNow();
            }
}


class myAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    public myAdmin(){
        super();

    }


}
```

}

log

```
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.deviceadmin.MainActivity$myAdmin: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.deviceadmin.MainActivity$myAdmin; no empty constructor
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2356)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:588)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.deviceadmin.MainActivity$myAdmin; no empty constructor
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2351)
08-16 14:46:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(17963):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Answer (score 0):

`myAdmin` needs to be a `public static` inner class, or else a separate `public` Java class. You have a non-`public`, non-`static` inner class, which will not work.